# How do you get a button read by screen readers like NVDA

Tags: c#, wpf, nvda

I've been really stuck on making this work, I have set up Automation helptext with data and automation name but NVDA is still not reading a button.
I've been looking at examples and some questions here but there is no direct answer.

```xml
<Grid Focusable="False">
    <Button x:Name="button" 
            Content="Button" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="372,235,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            IsCancel="True" 
            Click="button_Click" 
            AutomationProperties.Name="This is a button to be clicked.">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```